# Hyphenat not hyphenating words with hyphens

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation

I'm using the `hyphenat` package but it seems that it doesn't work with all words. I have a document with a lot of foreign Arabic words and this functionality is important.

My MWE,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{testhyphens}
\usepackage{hyphenat}

\hyphenation{
ha-kimm
sugh-ra
}

\begin{document}

\begin{checkhyphens}{}
al\-Hakimm
al\hyp{}Hakimm
\textit{al\hyp{}Hakimm}\\

al\-Sughra
al\hyp{}Sughra
\textit{al\hyp{}Sughra}\\

complication
\textit{complication}
\end{checkhyphens}

\end{document}
```

The output,

[image: Hyphenation output]

I expect `al-Sughra` to hyphenate as `al-Sugh-ra` but it doesn't. What could be the problem?

I will be using XeLaTeX in the end, so I would prefer a solution that will work there as well.

Comment: TeX never applies hyphenation rules on words already containing an explicit hyphen.

Comment: @egreg, please lookup  the `\hyp{}` command in the `hyphenat` manual. It deals with this scenario specifically. Also, the first word example shows that it does indeed hyphenate words with a hyphen in them already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeX doesn't apply hyphenation rules to words that explicitly contain a hyphen.

The `\hyp` command essentially produces a hyphen that's followed by a glob of glue, making it possible to apply hyphenation rules on the next word part.

<sub>**Technical note.** A *word*, in this context, is a run of characters having nonzero `\lccode`, starting from a glob of glue and ending at anything that doesn't fit the criterion.</sub>

Why isn't *Sughra* hyphenated in `al\hyp{}Sughra`? Because the default language is English, which has `\righthyphenmin` (minimum number of characters following an implicit hyphen) set to 3.

You *might* set `\righthyphenmin` to 2, but this will most likely produce wrong hyphenation of English words.

You can typeset your document and add, where necessary, `\-` in the needed places. Chances are you won't need to add many of these tokens. Otherwise, do

```
\newcommand{\alsughra}{Al-Sugh\-ra}
```

and use `\alsughra{}` in your document.

Comment: The part about `\righthyphenmin` is exactly what I was looking for. Setting it to 2 fixed the problem. Please add a snippet that shows how to change the value of `\righthyphenmin` so that I may accept your answer.

Comment: @KhalidHussain No, setting `\righthyphenmin` to 2 will produce wrong hyphenation of English words.